# Character class is not working for Arabic text column

Tags: mysql, regex, wildcard

By definition MySQL character class [...] matches any character within the brackets. So I used it for Arabic characters. And it is giving me empty set every time.
Here is my query:

```
select hadith_raw_ar from view_hadith_in_book where hadith_raw_ar like '%[بل]ت';
```

Comment: are the data in the db correctly saved with the right encoding? With this query you can check if it is utf8 SELECT default_character_set_name FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA S
WHERE schema_name = "schemaname";

Comment: yes it is utf8 character set name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Be definition mySQL character class [...] matches any character within
>   the brackets.

Umm, that inaccurate. The character class is actually part of Regex, *not MySQL*. However, you can still use Regex with MySQL, of course, but you need to use the keyword `REGEXP` instead of `LIKE`.

Now, if you're trying to match anything that starts with any character represented in your character class, you should be using a regex pattern that looks something like `^[...]` where you replace the `...` with the characters you want.

So, in your case, you'd need something like this:

```
SELECT hadith_raw_ar FROM view_hadith_in_book WHERE hadith_raw_ar REGEXP '^[تبل]';
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
SELECT  hadith_raw_ar 
FROM    view_hadith_in_book 
WHERE   hadith_raw_ar LIKE 'ت%' OR 
        hadith_raw_ar LIKE 'ب%' OR
        hadith_raw_ar LIKE 'ل%';
```

..when not using Regex.

---

### References:

- [Regex: Character Classes or Character Sets](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).
- [Using Regular Expressions with MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html).

Comment: Depending on the version you using, this Answer is _not_ correct about `REGEXP`.  (See my Answer.)  The equivalent `LIKE` & `OR` should work.  (`LIKE` was implemented differently than `REGEXP`.)

Answer (score 1):

With older versions, you cannot use character classes with LIKE or RLIKE and non-latin1 character sets.  (At least not and expect to get the right results.)

`REGEXP` is lame.  It looks only at bytes; 6 bytes in your character class, some of which are duplicated.  Here's the hex: `D8 AA D8 A8 D9 84`.

*Sometimes* you will *happen* to get the 'right' answer from `REGEXP`.  MariaDB has a decent REGEXP.  For example, `SELECT '٪' REGEXP '[تبل]';` returns true.  Note that I am testing for a Arabic percent sign - hex `D9AA`.  Note how I picked D9, which exists in some Arabic characters and AA.

The MySQL 8.0 manual implies that REGEXP might work correctly for Arabic.  (But not for Emoji and some Chinese characters.)  MariaDB has had PCRE built-in since 10.0.5.

Comment: I'm using mysql Ver 14.14

Comment: There is no 14.14.  Do `SELECT @@version;` or `mysqld --version`

Comment: ohh, that's 5.7.22

Comment: If i use same LIKE query in mysql 8. it will properly?

Comment: @FatimaZohra - No.  `LIKE` does not handle character classes (in any version).  `REGEXP` (`RLIKE`) in 8.0 (or in MariaDB) should work properly with your query.

Answer (score 0):

Use utf8_general_ci collection to insert any language characters

Comment: Collation _may_ have something to do with the intended test, but does _not_ have anything to do with character classes.